# Connecting to Google Spreadsheet using gspread not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, openssl, pyopenssl, gspread

I have a python script that I'm running from a system running openWrt that uses gspread to connect to a Google Spreadsheet.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import json
import gspread

from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
credentials = credentials.create_scoped(['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'])

#credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('YunToCloud-a9572c8560ed.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
sh = gc.open_by_key('1cgSD0VVSioqxxj_yS5CB060Dc6318NMllCBwDQ79DzI')
```

I tried this, which uses Google Credentials and I've also just tried ServiceAccount in oauth2client, but they both give me the same thing:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread-0.6.2-py2.7.egg/gspread/client.py", line 105, in open_by_key
    feed = self.get_spreadsheets_feed()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread-0.6.2-py2.7.egg/gspread/client.py", line 155, in get_spreadsheets_feed
    r = self.session.get(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread-0.6.2-py2.7.egg/gspread/httpsession.py", line 73, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gspread-0.6.2-py2.7.egg/gspread/httpsession.py", line 65, in request
    response = func(url, data=data, params=params, headers=request_headers, files=files, json=json)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 506, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='spreadsheets.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /feeds/spreadsheets/private/full (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:504: error:14090086:lib(20):func(144):reason(134)'),))
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

I've run this code on my Windows machine and it works fine every time. I believe it may have something to do with the packages I have installed on my openWRT system, but I've tried multiple fresh installs, installing different openSSL packages and whatnot. Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: you just have to wait, if you read the whole error it says `Max retries exceeded with url: /feeds/spreadsheets/private/full`

Comment: Are you sure? It does this every time, no matter how long i wait to send a request. Shouldn't this error only occur if I'm sending too many requests? Also, when I try this code from my windows machine, it works no problem.

Comment: I'll test it then

Comment: Try `pip install requests[security]`

Comment: I did, didn't work :(